# Django trans and url tags

Tags: django, internationalization

I want to translate a paragraph containing a URL in a Django 1.3 application.

```
<p>
    First <a href="{% url edit-profile username=user.username %}">edit your profile</a>, please.
</p>
```

Depending on the language, the text surrounded by `<a>` tags will surely change. How can I allow translators to decide on the link placement? Wrapping the entire thing in a `{% trans %}` causes an error:

```
<p>{% trans "First <a href='{% url edit-profile username=user.username %}'>edit your profile</a>, please." %}</p>
```

The error thrown is `TemplateSyntaxError: Searching for value. Unexpected end of string in column 64: trans "First <a href='{% url edit-profile username=user.username`.

How should I go about doing this? Do I have to determine the URL in the view, then pass that URL as a string to the template? That seems like a really convoluted solution for what I would think is a very common problem.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use `{% blocktrans %}`. The [Django translation docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/) include this example:

```
{% url path.to.view arg arg2 as the_url %}
{% blocktrans %}
This is a URL: {{ the_url }}
{% endblocktrans %}
```

Comment: Also don't work with named urls `{% url "my_url" as the_url %}`: gives `a format specification for argument 'the_url' doesn't exist in 'msgstr'`

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
{% url "app-name:name-of-view" as the_url %}
{% blocktrans %}
This is a URL: {{ the_url }}
{% endblocktrans %}
```